# Unions Data.Map singletons inside an IO

Tags: haskell

I am struggling with applying `Data.Map.unions` to a list of `Data.Map` singletons wrapped in an `IO`. Here is my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass    #-}

module Main where
  
import           Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.Aeson as JSON
import           GHC.Generics (Generic)
import           Data.Text.Lazy         (unpack)
import           Data.Text.Lazy.Builder (toLazyText)
import           Data.Aeson.Text        (encodeToTextBuilder)
import           System.IO
import           System.Directory
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy  as B
import           Data.Map.Internal.Debug (showTree)

data RoseTree a = RoseTree { value :: a, children :: [RoseTree a]}
                   deriving (Show, Generic, Functor, JSON.FromJSON, JSON.ToJSON)

type Structure = RoseTree Int 
type StructureList = [Structure]

type StructureMap = M.Map String Structure

dataDir :: FilePath
dataDir = "data"

v2s :: JSON.Value -> String
v2s = unpack . toLazyText . encodeToTextBuilder

saveToFile :: FilePath -> Structure -> IO ()
saveToFile dir structure = withFile ( dataDir ++ "/" ++ dir ++ "/" ++ dir ++ ".json") WriteMode $ \h -> System.IO.hPutStr h (v2s $ JSON.toJSON structure)

loadFromFile :: JSON.FromJSON a => FilePath -> IO a
loadFromFile filename = fmap (fromJust . JSON.decode) $ B.readFile ( dataDir ++ "/" ++ filename )

loadStructuresFromFilesystem :: IO StructureMap
loadStructuresFromFilesystem = do
  dirs <- listDirectory dataDir
  singletons <- map (\dir -> do
    structure <- ((loadFromFile (dataDir ++ "/" ++ dir ++ "/" ++ dir ++ ".json")) :: IO Structure)
    return $ M.singleton dir structure) dirs
  return $ M.unions singletons


testStructure1 :: Structure
testStructure1 = RoseTree 1 [RoseTree 2 [], RoseTree 3 []]

testStructure2 :: Structure
testStructure2 = RoseTree 2 [RoseTree 4 [], RoseTree 6 []]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  saveToFile "struct1" testStructure1
  saveToFile "struct2" testStructure2
  structureMap <- loadStructuresFromFilesystem
  putStrLn $ showTree structureMap
```

The error is following:

```
Main.hs:42:17: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: IO (IO (M.Map [Char] Structure))
        Actual type: [IO (M.Map [Char] Structure)]
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        singletons <- map
                        (\ dir
                           -> do structure <- ((loadFromFile
                                                  (dataDir
                                                     ++ "/" ++ dir ++ "/" ++ dir ++ ".json")) ::
                                                 IO Structure)
                                 return $ M.singleton dir structure)
                        dirs
      In the expression:
        do dirs <- listDirectory dataDir
           singletons <- map
                           (\ dir
                              -> do structure <- ((loadFromFile
                                                     (dataDir
                                                        ++ "/" ++ dir ++ "/" ++ dir ++ ".json")) ::
                                                    IO Structure)
                                    ....)
                           dirs
           return $ M.unions singletons
      In an equation for ‘loadStructuresFromFilesystem’:
          loadStructuresFromFilesystem
            = do dirs <- listDirectory dataDir
                 singletons <- map (\ dir -> do ...) dirs
                 return $ M.unions singletons
   |
42 |   singletons <- map (\dir -> do
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

Is there a way to apply unions to a list of singletons wrapped in `IO`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `singletons <- mapM ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda expression:

```
\dir -> do
    structure <- ((loadFromFile (dataDir ++ "/" ++ dir ++ "/" ++ dir ++ ".json")) :: IO Structure)
    return $ M.singleton dir structure)
```

has type `FilePath -> IO (M.Map [Char] Structure)`. This thus means that if you work with a `map`, you will obtain an `[IO M.Map [Char] Structure]`. But that will conflict with the type of `loadStructuresFromFilesystem`, which is an `IO StructureMap`.

Your expression needs to have as type `IO [M.Map [Char] Structure]`. We can do this by using [**`mapM :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:mapM):

```
loadStructuresFromFilesystem :: IO StructureMap
loadStructuresFromFilesystem = do
  dirs <- listDirectory dataDir
  singletons <- mapM (\dir -> do
      structure <- ((loadFromFile (dataDir ++ "/" ++ dir ++ "/" ++ dir ++ ".json")) :: IO Structure)
      return $ M.singleton dir structure
    ) dirs
  return $ M.unions singletons
```

We can further simplify the expression by a functor mapping over the `IO [M.Map [Char] Structure]` we obtained:

```
loadStructuresFromFilesystem :: IO StructureMap
loadStructuresFromFilesystem = do
  dirs <- listDirectory dataDir
  M.unions <$> mapM (\dir -> do
      structure <- ((loadFromFile (dataDir ++ "/" ++ dir ++ "/" ++ dir ++ ".json")) :: IO Structure)
      return $ M.singleton dir structure
    ) dirs
```

Comment: Generally, I'd recommend using `traverse` over `mapM`, since `traverse` is strictly more general. But yes, this is the right approach.